# Can I daisychain multiple Arduino Nanos to a single USB port (specialized purpose)

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, usb, serial-data

I need to have several Nanos on one USB port. They will have separate power, so power constraints won't be a concern. I need them all to go through the same serial port. They will never get anything sent to them, and should never send data simultaneously. Each one is connected to a switch, and upon pressing the switch, will send an 8-digit serial number over serial. I want to have a VB.NET application which listens over this shared serial COM for numbers, and collects them all, displaying them in a history list. Can this work?

Comment: No, they can't all share one data line.  What you'll need to do is either connect all of the switches to one Arduino or connect all of the Arduinos to one "master" arduino which will communicate with the computer.

Comment: The single Master Arduino is what I'll go with. "Master" and "Slave" boards, reminds me of IDE drives lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a USB topology to operate one needs a USB controller which knows about all the different USB protocols necessary to communicate with all the different USB peripherals (this is why a USB controller is usually a fully capable computer) all connected through a USB hub.  It is unlikely a USB network could be created using only peripheral USB devices which were wired directly together.

To communicate between several Arduinos and a computer it would be much easier to use a serial bus made for multiple drops like [RS485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485). There are many RS485 to USB converters available [like this one](https://www.alliedelec.com/product/ftdi/usb-rs485-we-1800-bt/70069439/) for computers that do not have an RS485 port.